# Deep Learning Dataset Design for a Image Reference to Different Classes?

Tags: image, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I want to training a image classifier using inception model.
Now, I have a dishes called chicken rice.
Suppose i want to create rice and chicken meat class.
So can i design output ground true probability as [0.5,0.5,0,0,0...]? 
In other words, If the target image contains two classes' content, what should I do to make it reasonable?

Do somebody has tried this?

I have tried to train the image separately, and google did this, too.

```
keycnt  = 0
imagcnt = 0
TestNumber_byclass = np.zeros([keycount],np.int32)
for key in TestKeys:
    TestNumber_byclass[keycnt] = len(json_data_test[key])
    for imagedata in json_data_test[key]: 
        imgdata = tf_resize_images(imagdir + imagedata + '.jpg')
        imgdata = np.array(imgdata, dtype = np.uint8)
        # make image center at 0 in the range of (-1,1]
        #imgdata = (imgdata - mean - 128) / 128
        h5f = h5py.File(h5filedir_test + str(imagcnt) + ".h5", "w")
        h5f.create_dataset('image', data=imgdata)
        h5f.create_dataset('label', data=keycnt)
        h5f.create_dataset('name' , data=key)
        h5f.close()
        imagcnt = imagcnt + 1
    keycnt =keycnt +1
    message = '\r[%d/%d] progress...' % (keycnt,keycount)
    sys.stdout.write(message)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You are asking about your system architecture or your code? Also are you referring to training or testing? Not a good idea to use images with mixed content in general

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is a multiclass classification, where M out of N classes will be predicted. This is usually done by setting the flag to 1 if the object appears in the image and setting it to 0 if that's not the case.

The really important piece of information is that the last activation function needs to be a sigmoid instead of a softmax. That way you decouple the confidence for each class from the other classes and the sum will be between 0 and N.